# iOS kSecUseOperationPrompt not used

Tags: ios, popup, ios11, face-id

I'm trying to get a generic passcode from the keychain encoded by Face ID, and with a **custom prompt/message** for the user.

This has been working for Touch ID but it seems that I'm not able to override the default text of 'Face Not Recognised' on the overlay that pops up in case of an unsuccessful scan.
How could I achieve to make the popup display the content of the message NSString.

```
NSDictionary *query = @{
        (id)kSecClass: (id)kSecClassGenericPassword,
        (id)kSecAttrService: self.keychainItemServiceName,
        (id)kSecAttrAccount: contract,
        (id)kSecReturnData: @YES,
        (id)kSecUseOperationPrompt: message
        };
OSStatus status = SecItemCopyMatching((__bridge CFDictionaryRef)query, &dataTypeRef);
```